# GRUB + Windows 7: Windows 7 can't sleep or hibernate

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, boot, grub, sleep

sorry for my bad english,

I installed GRUB on the MBR to have a dual boot on a Windows 7/Kubuntu PC. After doing this, the dual boot works fine, but I cannot put Windows 7 to sleep mode (the screen becomes black, but the computer stays active).
I read [this topic](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1341694) (note that the symptom is not exactly the same: the screen does not come back immediatly, it stays black until the mouse is moved or a key is pressed, but the computer itself does not sleep), but I have only one partition (containing everything) on my Windows disk (/dev/sda), which has already a "boot" flag. So what should I change ?

Do you have any help ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a well working solution!
It was simply to deactivate Windows 7 hibernation by typing `powercfg -h off` as administrator in the cmd...

However, I couldn't understand *why* it works, so I would appreciate any explanation :-)

Answer (score 0):

---

Reinstalling GRUB on your Linux partition might work.

---

X is the drive (letter) on which you want GRUB to write the boot information. Normally users should not include a partition number, which would produce an error message as the command would attempt to write the information to a partition.

Run `sudo grub-install /dev/sd[x]`, replacing [x] with the necessary value (for instance: `sudo grub-install /dev/sda`)

This will rewrite the information for the MBR (Master Boot Record) to point to the current installation and rewrite some of the GRUB 2 files (which were already working). Since it isn't done during execution of the previous command, running `sudo update-grub` after the install will ensure GRUB2's menu is up-to-date.

---

[Source](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing)

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked ! I don't know if this has any importance, but I installed GRUB on the Kubuntu hard disk (/dev/sdb), not the Windows one.

Comment: It works if the computer enters in sleeping mode just after booting, but after having being used some tens of minutes, it does just as before (the screen becomes black but the computer stays active)...  So the situation is better than before, but it is not completely working...

Comment: I'll Try To Give Some More Help Soon!